# Can you suggest an emulator for Iphone or Ipad which really works on window based PCs?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad

I have came across several such like Ipad peek & several others for Iphone but none seemed to work properly (even CSS fixed positioning seemed to work in all of them which is not possible in IPhone).

I am cool with with any online or desktop based solution that really provides at least close(if not perfect) results & is compatible with any verison of windows.

---

Please don't suggest to just buy it as it is not feasible for me to do that for just a single project.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just use Google Chrome scaled down to the iPhone screen resolution with some interface hacks for touch, etc.? If you want similar rendering, then Chrome should work just fine. Functionality would be hard, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fun ;-)

http://alexw.me/ipad2/

http://www.le-bidouilleur.fr/ipad/

http://www.testiphone.com/

http://www.marketcircle.com/iphoney/

http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/

http://zambetti.com/projects/liveview/ (not sure of what it is)

http://ahl1.over-blog.com/article-telecharger-emulateur-ipad-tuto-67686581.html (not sure of what it is)

Answer (score 0):

Links to a couple iPhone browser simulators on Windows:

http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/

http://iphonesimulator.net/

Answer (score 0):

Used iPod touch is compatible with Windows, and less than $200 on EBay.